# Cleaning the graphics clean all the graphics

Tags: java, button, graphics, transparent

I have a little problem with the Java Graphics, I have my special JComponent, a Textured Button. When the mouse is on, the button become a little brighter (it become filled by a semi-transparent white), but the graphics are not cleaning, so the transparent-white make a full white background on the component, even when the mouse is not on the button. It looks like this:

[image: My bugged button]

So I found a solution, I added this:

```
super.paintComponent(g);

// Clearing
((Graphics2D) g).setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC));
g.setColor(Swinger.TRANSPARENT);
g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
```

On my component paintComponent method, so it worked! But, it doesn't clean only the button background, it clean all behind it! Looks like this without the button:

[image: Without the button]

And with the button:

[image: With the button]

You can see IDEA in background.

Here is my code (See the fr.theshark34.swinger.textured.STexturedButton class) :
https://github.com/TheShark34/Swinger

Comment: Set you component to be transparent by using `setOpaque` and pass it `false`, you will then need to be sure to take over filling the component with your transparent color ;)

Comment: If i do this, and I remove my cleaning code, it works, it doesn't delete the window, but if i am on a transparent background, it do the same as the first GIF.

Comment: It would help greatly if you post your full code...

Comment: I edited the post, this is a library.

Comment: So, having looked over you code, I would suggest two things, 1- use `setOpaque(false)` to make the button transparent, then your `TRANSPARENT` fill color will make sense and get rid of `setBounds` in favour of `getPreferredSize`.  Swing only handles opaque or transparent components, and only the the `opaque` property, it doesn't know how to handle alpha based colors (or more importantly, it doesn't use this information when determining if the are behind the component should be painted or not)

Comment: I tried, adding setOpaque(false) doesn't change anything, with or without the cleaning code :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have a lack of understanding or a misunderstanding into how painting works in Swing, in either case, it's kind of scary.

You might like to take a closer look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about how painting works in Swing

In your `STexturedButton` class, you don't need to do...

```
((Graphics2D) g).setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC));
g.setColor(Swinger.TRANSPARENT);
g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
```

as Swing will have already (basically) done it for you (as `STexturedButton` extends from your `AbstractButton` class, which extends from `JComponent` which is transparent by default, if the component weren't transparent, doing what you've done would have been dangerous and ended in no end of additionally weird paint artefacts).

So in my testing, I just took it out.

Also, I'd prefer to override `getPreferredSize` instead of providing your own `setBounds` methods, it's confusing for a start (as the component already has a it's own `setBounds` methods and using `getPreferredSize` plays well with the existing Swing API)

Since you've not provided any kind of runnable example, I had to make my own, but the changes work just fine for me.

[image: Normal][image: Highlighted]

```
import fr.theshark34.swinger.textured.STexturedButton;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.LinearGradientPaint;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            try {
                STexturedButton btn = new STexturedButton(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/Pony.png")));
                add(btn);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            LinearGradientPaint lgp = new LinearGradientPaint(
                    new Point(0, 0),
                    new Point(0, getHeight()),
                    new float[]{
                        0.1428571428571429f,
                        0.2857142857142858f,
                        0.4285714285714287f,
                        0.5714285714285716f,
                        0.7142857142857145f,
                        0.8571428571428574f,
                        1f
                    },
                    new Color[]{Color.RED, Color.ORANGE, Color.GREEN, Color.YELLOW, Color.BLUE, Color.MAGENTA, Color.PINK}
            );
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setPaint(lgp);
            g2d.fill(new Rectangle(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight()));
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

## Now with a working transparent window example

[image: Transparent Panel and Window]

```
import fr.theshark34.swinger.textured.STexturedButton;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.LinearGradientPaint;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setUndecorated(true);
                frame.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            setOpaque(false);

            try {
                STexturedButton btn = new STexturedButton(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/Pony.png")));
                add(btn);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED));
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Ok I will remember for the getPrefferedSize =) but, I said it, without the cleaning code it works, but on a transparent background (a transparent JPanel on a transparent JFrame) it does like the first GIF i gave :/

Comment: Then you're doing it wrong. Don't use alpha based colors as background colors, you must use setOpaque. Instead of posing gifs post code that we can run and see what you're doing

Comment: @TheShark34 Now updated with working example of transparent panel and window (based on previous modifications)

Comment: I don't understand, it wasn't working with me, I think it's because the layout was null. Thanks you so much MadProgrammer =)